Laravel Blade prevent using compromised passwords
I have a system on my site made to update user passwords. Within the controller is the function update.
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use App\Models\User;

...

public function update(User $user): RedirectResponse
    {
        // Validate input
        $validated = request()->validate([
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user->password = Hash::make($validated['password']);
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('user-manager')->with('success', 'User updated successfully.');
    }

I have tried using Password::defaults() and Password::min(8)->uncompromised() but both allow passwords like Password1! or Password!234 (both verified as leaked by https://haveibeenpwned.com/ which is where the function checks). What am I missing here?
